# Не работает слот в Qt

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь поставить обработчик события на кнопку, но он почему-то не работает. В консоли вывода приложения пишет: QObject::connect: No such slot QDialog::okButtonPressed()

Вот код:

```
class BooksEditDialog : public QDialog {
public:
    BooksEditDialog(Books *bk);
    QString getName_book() const;
    QString getName_author() const;
    QString getGenre() const;
    QString getPublisher() const;
    int getYear() const;
    int getPage() const;
    double getPrice() const;
    void setBooks(Books *bk);
    void setValidator(QRegExpValidator *nameValidator);
private:
    void createComboBox();
    void createWidgets();
    void connectSlots();
    void placeWidgets();
    void initValidation();
    QDialogButtonBox *buttons;
    QLineEdit *name_bookEdit;
    QLineEdit *name_authorEdit;
    QComboBox *genreEdit;
    QLineEdit *publisherEdit;
    QSpinBox *yearEdit;
    QSpinBox *pageEdit;
    QDoubleSpinBox *priceEdit;
public slots:
    void okButtonPressed();
};

void BooksEditDialog::okButtonPressed() {
QString str = name_authorEdit->text();
int p = 0;
if (name_authorEdit->validator()->validate(str, p) != QValidator::Acceptable) {
   QMessageBox::critical(this, "Name is not complete!",
   "The name of organization consists of letters, numbers, spaces, +, -!!!\n "
   "Name begins with an uppercase letter");
   name_authorEdit->setFocus();
   return;
}
accept();
}
void BooksEditDialog::connectSlots() {
    connect(buttons, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(okButtonPressed()));
    connect(buttons, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте Q_OBJECT после class BooksEditDialog : public QDialog {

Comment: не помогло, посыпались ошибки:

    C:\Users\user\books\bookseditdialog.cpp:3: ошибка: undefined reference to `vtable for BooksEditDialog'

    C:\Users\user\books\bookseditdialog.cpp:3: ошибка: undefined reference to `vtable for BooksEditDialog'

    collect2.exe:-1: ошибка: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: так и должно быть. Потому что в ответе ошибка. Не нужно добавлять Q_OBJECT

Comment: а не подскажете в чём ошибка ?

Comment: Это почему, вдруг, не нужно добавлять?

1. добавить
2. разделить объявление и определение класса по разным файлам (*.h и *.cpp соответственно)
3. прогнать через moc

Comment: на .h и .cpp все разделено
как прогнать через moc

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/moc.html

Comment: Bulid -> clean all;

Build -> run QMake;